# MySQL update query based on a DATE

Tags: mysql

I have a query than runs fine as 2 distinct parts but I cannot join them with a WHERE clause, 
The 'My Date' field is a text field that I want to just use the first part of the string (The Date)to get an update based on a date range of 30 days

Trying this

```
UPDATE metrics.table1 as master 
    LEFT JOIN metrics.table2 as feed ON master.hostname = feed.`hostname`
    SET master.column1 = True 
where
(SELECT CAST(`My Date` AS DATE)
FROM `metrics`.`table2`
WHERE `My Date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
AND NOW())
;
```

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-09-17 11:00:39 UTC'

The select part runs fine on it's own?

Comment: If the date column is TEXT then you cannot use `DATE_SUB()` as that expects a `DATE` or `DATETIME` data type. or the `NOW()` as that returns a DATETIME. **This** among other reasons is why dates should always be stored in DATE or DATETIME data type columns

Comment: You are now comdemed to work out some complex text manipulation and conversions to date in the query, possible but a bit of a pain

Comment: What format is `\`My Date\`` in

Comment: In MySQL it is also a good idea NOT to have spaces in column names, or mixed case column names

Comment: `My Date`  format example is '2019-09-17 11:00:39 UTC' as a string,

Comment: the select part of the query runs fine as a standalone query

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are casting your Mydate for select Statement and not for Where condition.Hence cast Mydate in where condition also as follows,

```
 SELECT CAST(`My Date` AS DATE)
 FROM `metrics`.`table2`
 WHERE CAST(`My Date` AS DATE) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
 AND NOW())
```

Comment: This works as a standalone query but not with the WHERE clause, same error, Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2019-09-17 11:00:39 UTC'

Comment: @SneakyPurple can you check it now..?

Comment: same again, the SELECT runs fine, but whenever I use it as part of a where clause it return the date error

Comment: @SneakyPurple Can you try STR_TO_DATE instead of cast in where clause.?